# Try Except Statement to Test for Presence of Error Button, Throw Exception if Element Found

Tags: python, selenium, try-catch, assertion, webpage-screenshot

I have written a Python / Selenium Script to automate a work flow on a financial site.

One of the tests involves checking for the presence of error text on one of the screens.

Attached is a Try / Except block that checks for the presence of a button (id = errorShowMore). If the button displays, I want the script to Fail and I want to take a screenshot of the page.

I wrote code that identifies the error button. I then put this code into a Try / Except Block.

However, I have questions on how to improve this error handling structure (if it can be improved).

```
try:
    showMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_id("errorShowMore")
    assert showMoreButton.click() except AssertionError:
    screenshot_name = "FAIL" + "_" + test_case_ID + "_" + browser + "_" + env + "_" + time_stamp + ".png"
    saved_screenshot_location = str(screenshot_directory / screenshot_name)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(saved_screenshot_location)
    raise
```

When I run the code and the error exists, I get an "AssertionError" (expected), screenshot is taken (expected) and script stops (expected).

However, I feel like I am missing something.

Is there a better way to check for the presence of the error button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `find_elements_by_id` and get the count.

```
errEleCount = len(driver.find_elements_by_id("errorShowMore"))
if errEleCount>0:
  # implement the logic here.
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try your recommendation.

Comment: Using your suggestion, I modified code as follows

        errorDisplays = False

        if driver.find_element_by_id("errorShowMore").is_displayed():
            errorDisplays = True
        else:
            pass
   
  try:
            assert errorDisplays is False
        except AssertionError:
            screenshot_name = "FAIL" + "_" + test_case_ID + "_" + browser + "_" + env + "_" + time_stamp + ".png"
            saved_screenshot_location = str(screenshot_directory / screenshot_name)
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file(saved_screenshot_location)
            raise